# Hibernate mapping : Getting exception - Cannot delete or update a parent row hibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have two classes

Book and DeliveryRequest now I want that when an object of Book is deleted then all requests corresponding to that book gets deleted as well.

delivery request class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Delivery_Request")
public class DeliveryRequest{

        private int deliveryRequestId;
        private Book book; 
        private User user;


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="Delivery_Request_Id")
        public int getDeliveryRequestId() {
            return deliveryRequestId;
        }

        public void setDeliveryRequestId(int deliveryRequestId) {
            this.deliveryRequestId = deliveryRequestId;
        }

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="Book_Id")
        public Book getBook() {
            return book;
        }

        public void setBook(Book book) {
            this.book = book;
        }

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="User_Id")
        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

}
```

Book class

```
 @Entity
public class Book {
        private int bookId;

        private Set<DeliveryRequest> requests = new HashSet<DeliveryRequest>(0);

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="Book_Id")
        public int getBookId() {
            return bookId;
        }
        public void setBookId(int bookId) {
            this.bookId = bookId;
        }       

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER , cascade=CascadeType.ALL , mappedBy="book")
        public Set<DeliveryRequest> getRequests() {
            return requests;
        }
        public void setRequests(Set<DeliveryRequest> requests) {
            this.requests = requests;
        }


}
```

What can be done to provide this cascading effect.

Comment: What is wrong with your example? On first, looks like it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for delete-cascade.

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
```